# Inviting Users to Events via Facebook API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, facebook

I'm able to create an event via the Facebook Graph API but I have yet to see a way in which to invite users to that event.

My fallback is to simply use the old REST API but sooner or later that will be phased out so I wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions.

--

Additional side question:

While using the REST API (or possibly even the Graph API) I have not found a way to invite guests who are not on Facebook. Is there a way to do this?

--

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is that I think you're stuck with the REST API, at least I couldn't find another way (see http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10070 if you haven't already). The good news is that there's still so much functionality missing from the graph API that I'm pretty sure Facebook isn't going to be phasing it out any time soon. Very frustrating though...

Answer (score 0):

can I use the JavaScript SDK to call the old REST API method ?

[JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api)